# how to communicate with my apps using IP address and socket remotely

Tags: node.js, server, client, electron

I am to Electron and nodejs 
And stuck here, actually i m making a desktop app to control every PC in network.  which tells me the ip and mac of computers in the network. But now I need to talk to it and push/get some message. but how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.io is likely the easiest way to do what you are trying to do. It'll allow you to communicate between the machines with a relatively low amount of effort.

Sockets generally work on a "server" and "client" basis, so you may want a central server that will coordinate with the clients.

[This blog post from node source provides a really good intro to using them.](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-socketio/)